# Как пользоваться функцией INSTR для mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Нужен такой запрос: выбрать столбик `header` в таблице `catalog` и вывести из него все записи, в которых в столбце `menu_id` в контексте существуют значения, например `"aaab"`.
Я нашёл альтернативную функцию PHP `strpos`, для MySQL - это `INSTR`. 
И вообщем собрал такой запрос

```
$query ='SELECT header FROM catalog WHERE INSTR(menu_id, "aaab")';
$catalog = Core::getInstance()->db->select($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($catalog)){
   echo $row['header'] .'<br/>';
}
```

Но ничего не выводит из базы данных.
Помогите.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `header` FROM `catalog` WHERE `menu_id` LIKE '%aaab%'
```

P.S. Зачем query делать с помощью PDO, а fetch с помощью `mysql_fetch_array()`? Остановитесь на чем-то одном.

Comment: Да это чужой код. Я даже не знаю как с помощью pdo превратить его в массив

Comment: прочитайте про функцию `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` по ссылке http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php